# react native error: node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:24 in createError

Tags: reactjs

I wrote this fonction

```
fetchWeather(){
    axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${this.state.city},uk&APPID=3a31a881817a041a63eac1c1bbbba705`)
    .then((response)=>{
      this.setState({report:response.data})
    }).catch((error)=>console.log(error))
  }
```

and get this error:

> node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:24 in createError
>   - node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:6 in settle
>   - ... 10 more stack frames from framework internals

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the url. CodeSandbox apparently blocks `http` requests. Change to `https`

Answer (score 1):

According to the axios [GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/core/settle.js) code (axios/lib/core/settle.js):

```
reject(createError(
      'Request failed with status code ' + response.status,
      response.config,
      null,
      response.request,
      response
    ));
```

The response was rejected because of an invalid status code (most likely an HTML 401). Check if your api key is still valid, or test your URL in postman.

EDIT: Below is a working code snippet based on the new URL

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
    this.state={
     report: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=3a31a881817a041a63eac1c1bbbba705`)
  .then((response)=>{
   this.setState({report:response.data});
    console.log(response.data);
  }).catch((error)=>console.log(error))
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>Report: {JSON.stringify(this.state.report)}</div>;
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.16.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: I changed the api to : api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=3a31a881817a041a63eac1c1bbbba705 but I get the same error

Comment: @tiakocedrickdeco Your new api key is indeed valid. I managed to make a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Robb216/jzgadf4t/). Make sure your url is set to `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=3a31a881817a041a63eac1c1bbbba705`